# How do i print this pattern of codes in C program

Tags: c, variables

```
int age=21;

float pi=3.14;

char my_char='a';

double big_pi=3.14223232323232122
```

how do I print this lines of codes in C program

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What exactly is your question? This seems to be valid C code (except for the missing `;` at the last line).

Answer (score 0):

//Use printf to print your variable

printf("float pi = %f", pi);

printf("char my_char = \'%c\'", my_char);

printf("double big_pi=%f", big_pi);